# Export AWS resources from one account to another

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an ALB created in my AWS account which is attached to an autoscaling group. I want to move the ALB and autoscaling group to another account. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/account-transfer-ec2-instance/), its not possible:

> **It's not possible** to transfer existing instances between AWS accounts.

You have to do it manually, as indicated in the link provided.

If you provisioned your ALB and ASG by means of CloudFormation, then you basically need to just share and copy underlying EBS volume snapshots with the second account if they contain some important information which can't be recreated from the templates.

Comment: Can I transfer other AWS resources like S3 and RDS from one account to another?